# De Casteljau algorithm ignore a control point

Tags: python, algorithm, interpolation, bezier

I wrote an implementation of the De Casteljau algorithm to create a Bezier curve. My problem is the function ignores the second control point, it does calculate some kind of curve, but it is not correct.

```
def DeCasteljau(CNTRL_P, t):
    ReP = points.point()
    Ret = points.point()

    n = len(CNTRL_P)
    k = 0
    tmp = 0

    while k < n:
        tmp = (((1 - t)**((n-1) - k))  *  (t**k))
        ReP.addP(CNTRL_P[k])
        #ReP.Prnt()
        ReP.mulP(tmp)   
        Ret.addP(ReP)
        ReP.Clr() #ReP => (0,0)
        tmp = 0
        k = k + 1

    return Ret
```

For example: CNTRL_P = [P0, P1, P2]
It ignores P1

```
class point():
    def __init__(self, X = 0, Y = 0):
        self.x = X
        self.y = Y

    def addP(self, P1):
        self.x = self.x + (P1.getX()) 
        self.y = self.y + (P1.getY())

    def subP(self, C = 0, D = 0):
        self.x = self.x - C
        self.y = self.y - D

    def mulP(self, C):
        self.x = self.x * C
        self.y = self.y * C

    def getX(self):
        a = self.x
        return a

    def getY(self):
        a = self.y
        return a

    def Prnt(self):
        print "X:", self.x,"Y:", self.y

    def Clr(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
```

Comment: What is `points` (and `points.point`)

Comment: Points is a class, which handle the points, it has two coordinates, and you can modify them.

Comment: That's not very helpful; what is the library or where is the code.  Also, why aren't you using a `for` loop (`for k, point in enumerate(CNTRL_P): ...`)

Comment: I've added the point class.

Comment: Btw, I've tested how the curve should look like with a function which calculates 3rd and an another which calculates 4th degree Bezier curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation looks faulty. Where's the recursion?

Does this give you better results?

```
def DeCasteljau2(CNTRL_P, t):

    tmp_points = CNTRL_P[:]

    while len(tmp_points) > 1:

        for k in range(len(tmp_points)-1):
            ReP = point()
            ReP2 = point()

            ReP.addP(tmp_points[k])
            ReP2.addP(tmp_points[k+1])

            ReP.mulP((1-t))
            ReP2.mulP(t)

            ReP.addP(ReP2)
            tmp_points[k] = ReP

        tmp_points.pop()

    return tmp_points[0]
```

This is the result after each iteration:

> P0 | P1 | P2
>
> P0 * (1-t) + P1 * t | P1 * (1-t) + P2
>
> (P0 * (1-t) + P1 * t)*(1-t) + (P1 * (1-t) + P2)*t

You repeat the algorithm until you only have 1 point left. Each point `P(n)` in the next solution is the result of `P(n) * (1-t) + p(n+1) * t` from the last solution. At each iteration the last point is discarded since there is no next point that you could multiply and add with.

Wikipedia probably can explain that better than me: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm#Geometric_interpretation)

Comment: Could you explain your solution? I mean you take two points you multiple them by (1-t) and t, after that you add them, and the kth element of the tmp_points will be equal with ReP. So basically you overwrite one of the  tmp_points in every cycle? Do I get it right?
Like: tmp_points = [P0,P1, P2] 
=> tmp_points = [new_value, P1, P2]
=> tmp_points = [new_value, new_Value, P2]
...

Comment: I simply looked up the algorithm on wikipedia. I'll try to explain it in more detail by editing the answer.